# Know what command the application is executing

Tags: python, c++, windows, shell, console

So every interactive application should have commands that are called when corresponding action are done. So let's say we're using a Windows 10 application. We'll just use the chrome for example. There must be functions that are called when we do actions like open the options menu, open a new tab, go to a website. So is there any console or protocol that we can listen and find out what commands that are run when the action is performed.

Something like an Arduino serial console, where like when you open the options menu maybe it'll log something like:

```
> menu.option.open()
> ["menu properties"]
```

So basically it'll log the function/command that's run whatever the action is performed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You're assuming far too much about how applications, and window systems, work.

Comment: ***So is there any console or protocol that we can listen and find out what commands that are run when the action is performed.*** No applications generally don't log or tell the OS each time they do something.

Comment: ***Is there a way to achieve this?*** You may be able to use Spy++ to see what windows are clicked and what buttons are pressed and other information.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2017 If you understand the info you may be able to use a hook to capture the same info. With that said what you learn may only  be valid for the exact same software version you examine.

Comment: @drescherjm ***No applications generally don't log or tell the OS each time they do something.*** but functions need to be called in order to be executed, then why can't you listen to it? Something like when A calls B to go buy a drink, C must be able to stand beside them and hear the command that A passes to B. Aren't it?